# Installing ppa gnome 3.18 themes problem

Tags: gnome, themes, customization

I'm having trouble installing a custom theme on Ubuntu gnome 16.04.  I downloaded the "hardy" then from Diviant Art.  I unzipped file into a new folder ".theme".  I cannot download into usr/share/theme...its under root permissions.  I can see the files in the folder, but the Gnome tweak tool does not see them.  I've turned on the accept extensions setting, and attempted to change the path for themes in the tweak tool.  But still nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'll give it a try as soon as I can.  I'll let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo` to gain root permissions.

**In General**
Assuming you’ve downloaded the Paper theme* and extracted it to the folder `~/Downloads/themes/Paper`

```
cd ~/Downloads/themes
sudo cp -rf Paper /usr/share/themes
```

**Hardy Theme by MariuxV?**
If the theme you’re using is [this one](http://mariuxv.deviantart.com/art/Hardy-Theme-75628261) then it’s a little more complicated since there are multiple different kinds of themes and profiles in that file. The one that is probably useful for you is in the GTK folder inside the archive file.

So if you extracted the archive to `~/Downloads/themes/Hardy-Mariux 2.0`…

```
cd ~/Downloads/themes/Hardy-Mariux 2.0/GTK
sudo cp -rf "Hardy-Mariux 2.0" /usr/share/themes
```

To install any of the other customisations you’d need to look at the `readme.txt` file in the top folder of the extracted archive.

**Another Option**
I notice that the basic theme is also available as [a .deb file](http://mariuxv.deviantart.com/art/Hardy-Theme-Debian-Package-85558797).

Assuming you downloaded it to `~/Downloads/themes/hardy_theme_debian_package_by_mariuxv.deb`…

```
cd ~/Downloads/themes
sudo apt install hardy_theme_debian_package_by_mariuxv.deb
```

You could also right-click on the file in a file manager and choose Open With Software Install to install it using Ubuntu Software Center.

* Just an example—Paper theme has a PPA.

Comment: Yes they are themes, plural. Yes, I believe I have the user themes ext installed.  I can do sudo commands.

Comment: If you have ``sudo`` then you can just copy the theme folder to ``/usr/share/themes`` and that should work if the shell extension isn’t working.

Comment: I don't have permissions to usr/share/themes.

Comment: See the edited answer above.

Comment: I was able to move theme folder into my usr/share/thmemes folder...via install nautilus.  I was only able to do a couple of the read.txt  instructions.  I still see nothing via Tweak Tool, accept one new background.